# SQL : Syntax ERROR 1064 (42000): can't identify the issue?

Tags: mysql, syntax

[image: Client table that i want to Create]

I typed this code :

[image: TABLE Client CODE]

When i execute the command i got the message below :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ') ENGINE=InnoDB' at line 6

Could you please help to solve this issue?

Comment: remove comma after email field declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove , after email in the table creation

```
CREATE TABLE Client 
(numero int unsigned primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, 
nom varchar(40) NOT NULL,
prenom varchar(40) NOT NULL,
email varchar(40) NOT NULL)
ENGINE =InnoDB;
```

Comment: @MewX86 remove , after email.

Comment: Thank you it works fine, but i want to know why "," create this issue ?

Comment: Because there is no column after email

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation.